# Window keeps getting black and white when left mouse button get pressed - C++, SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

This is my code, I wanted to make a clone of Paint, but when I press the mouse left button to draw, the window gets black first and then it checks the button pression again and then draws the black circles. Another problem that I have is that it's too slow to draw the circles and when I move the mouse while pressing the button, I get some blank spaces beetween the black circles.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

using std::cin, std::cout, std::string;
using namespace sf;

int main() {
    RenderWindow w(VideoMode(1280, 900), "w", Style::Close);
    Event e;
    w.clear(Color::White);
    w.display();
    CircleShape pixel(5.f);
    pixel.setFillColor(Color::Black);
    int i = 0;

    while (w.isOpen()) {
        while (w.pollEvent(e)) {
            if (e.type == Event::Closed) {
                w.close();
            }
            while (e.type == Event::MouseButtonPressed) {
                pixel.setPosition(Mouse::getPosition(w).x - 5, Mouse::getPosition(w).y - 5);
                w.draw(pixel);
                w.display();
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this an infinite loop `while (e.type == Event::MouseButtonPressed)`?

Comment: No, I also get this if I put "if" instead of "while", I needed while to make my program to draw while I move the mouse

Comment: I think SFML's pollEvent only returns events when there are events in the queue. If this is the case, then in theory, your rendering code will never update when there are no events to process. Maybe your rendering code should be outside the event-processing loop and the event-processing loop should modify some state variables rather than call the rendering code directly...

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried two approaches, yours - slightly modified and my with SF::VertexArray.
First of all, you have to [clear your window](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-draw.php#the-drawing-window) (scroll down and read the red box) to not have a flashy screen, but how to keep what you drew?

- The solution to that is off-screen drawing - SF::RenderTexture.

Second, the gaps in lines - there are not enough frames to keep track of your cursor. What it means is that your mouse between frames moved more than your "pixel" width or height.

- How to fix it? Have something like a cursor movement buffer or just predict where your mouse was between frames by using a line equation (gets "blocky" on low fps).

Your approach:

```
int main() {
    RenderWindow w(VideoMode(1280, 900), "w", Style::Close);
    Event e;
    CircleShape pixel(5.f);
    pixel.setFillColor(Color::Black);
    RenderTexture renderTexture;
    renderTexture.create(1280, 900);
    sf::Sprite sprite(renderTexture.getTexture());
    bool mousePressed = false;
    Vector2f lastMousePos(Mouse::getPosition(w).x - 5, Mouse::getPosition(w).y - 5);
    Vector2f newMousePos;
    float a;
    float b;
    Vector2f deltaPos;
    while (w.isOpen()) {
        newMousePos = Vector2f(Mouse::getPosition(w).x - 5, Mouse::getPosition(w).y - 5);
        while (w.pollEvent(e)) {
            if (e.type == Event::Closed) {
                w.close();
            }
            if (e.type == Event::MouseButtonPressed) {
                mousePressed = true;
            }
            if (e.type == Event::MouseButtonReleased) {
                mousePressed = false;
            }
            if (e.type == Event::KeyPressed && e.key.code == Keyboard::Space) {
                renderTexture.clear(Color::White); //clearing window
            }
        }
        w.clear(Color::Blue);
        if (mousePressed) {
            deltaPos = lastMousePos - newMousePos;
            a = deltaPos.y / deltaPos.x; // y = a*x + b (Line equation)
            b = lastMousePos.y - (deltaPos.y / deltaPos.x * lastMousePos.x);

            if (deltaPos.x != 0) {
                if (deltaPos.x < 0) {
                    for (float x = lastMousePos.x; x < newMousePos.x;) {
                        pixel.setPosition(x, x * a + b);
                        x += 0.1f;
                        renderTexture.draw(pixel);
                    }
                }
                else
                    for (float x = lastMousePos.x; x > newMousePos.x;) {
                        pixel.setPosition(x, x * a + b);
                        x -= 0.1f;
                        renderTexture.draw(pixel);
                    }
            }
            else {
                if (deltaPos.y != 0) {
                    if (deltaPos.y < 0) {
                        for (float y = lastMousePos.y; y < newMousePos.y;) {
                            pixel.setPosition(lastMousePos.x, y);
                            y += 0.1f;
                            renderTexture.draw(pixel);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        for (float y = lastMousePos.y; y > newMousePos.y;) {
                            pixel.setPosition(lastMousePos.x, y);
                            y -= 0.1f;
                            renderTexture.draw(pixel);
                        }
                }
                else {
                    pixel.setPosition(lastMousePos);
                    renderTexture.draw(pixel);
                }
                renderTexture.display();
            }
        }
        
        sf::Sprite sprite(renderTexture.getTexture());
        
        w.draw(sprite);
        w.display();
        lastMousePos = newMousePos;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The other version, however, has a big downside - lines have no thickness. You can fix it using sf::quads instead of sf::lines, but it needs more coding and math.
sf::Lines solution:

```
int main() {
    RenderWindow w(VideoMode(1280, 900), "w", Style::Close);
    Event e;
    RenderTexture renderTexture;
    renderTexture.create(1280, 900);
    sf::Sprite sprite(renderTexture.getTexture());
    bool mousePressed = false;
    Vector2f lastMousePos;
    Vector2f newMousePos(Mouse::getPosition(w).x, Mouse::getPosition(w).y);
    VertexArray myLine(Lines, 2);
    myLine[0].color = Color::Black;
    myLine[1].color = Color::Black;

    while (w.isOpen()) {
        lastMousePos = newMousePos;
        newMousePos = Vector2f(Mouse::getPosition(w).x, Mouse::getPosition(w).y);
        while (w.pollEvent(e)) {
            if (e.type == Event::Closed) {
                w.close();
            }
            if (e.type == Event::MouseButtonPressed) {
                mousePressed = true;
            }
            if (e.type == Event::MouseButtonReleased) {
                mousePressed = false;
            }
            if (e.type == Event::KeyPressed && e.key.code == Keyboard::Space) {
                renderTexture.clear(Color::White);
            }
        }
        w.clear(Color::White);

        myLine[0].position = lastMousePos;
        myLine[1].position = newMousePos;
        if (mousePressed) {
            renderTexture.draw(myLine);
            renderTexture.display();
        }
        
        
        sf::Sprite sprite(renderTexture.getTexture());
        
        w.draw(sprite);
        w.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But in both versions there is a bug that looks like this:

[image]

And I can't figure out why, even though in the 2nd code I don't do any math and it still occurs. So maybe someone will figure it out (made this post as a Community wiki, edit if you know what might be wrong), but for now treat my code as a guide, not as a solution.

Comment: Thx for the solution mate, I'm a beginner and I didn't understand your code, I'll study and try to make a solution by myself with these new concepts.